# Change layers names in existing layout legend only

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, legend, layouts

I am currently working on a QGIS plugin with QGIS version 3.34.0-Prizren and Python version 3.9.5.

I have a QGIS project containing several layers (the sources are tables from a Postgre database) sorted into groups and sub groups. The layers present in the Layer Panel must not be changed.

I also have a layout, made from a template. In that layout, I have a map item and a legend item. They are automatically updated for each new calcul run with the plugin.

My issue is the following : When they are displayed in the legend item, the layers names are the same as in the Layers Panel, which is not what I want, since these are the names of the tables.

I want to be able to change the names of some of my layers only in the legend of the layout.

Here is how I get the legend item in my code :

```
project, layout = self.loadTemplateInsideLayout(project, layout, myTemplate, 'My Plugin')
legendItem = layout.itemById("MyLegend")
legendModel = legendItem.model()
legendTree = legendModel.rootGroup()
```

And here is a test I made :

```
for root_node in legendTree.children():
    root_node.setName("New Label")
```

However it fails, because it changes the names of the layers and groups in the Layers Panel !

I also tried this :

```
for row in range(legendModel.rowCount()):
    legendNode = legendModel.index(row, 0)
    layerName = legendNode.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
    if layerName =="My Layer":
        # Update the label for the corresponding layer
        legendModel.setData(legendNode, 'New Label', Qt.EditRole)
    
     layerName = legendNode.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
     print("layerName = ", layerName)
 legendItem.refresh()
```

It fails too : the label does not change in the layout legend.

I also tried this :

```
for tr in legendItem.model().rootGroup().children():
    if tr.name() == "My Layer":
    tr.setCustomProperty("legend/title-label", "New Label")
```

Same thing : nothing changes in the legend item.

I went through the QgsLayerTreeNode documentation, but I did not find anything useful.

Is there a way to change the names of the entries in an existing legend item ?

Comment: It still changes the layer name in the Layer Panel. And it did not even change the label in the layout legend item.